# Check if columns of one data frame are present in another data frame with non-zero element in R

Tags: r

I want to check if columns of one data frame are present in another data frame and the values of those columns in the second data frame should be non zero. For example,

I have a data frame `df1` as follows:

```
indx1   indx2
aa 1     ac
ac       tg 0
```

I have another data frame `df` as follows:

```
col1    aa 1    ab 2    ac  bd 5    tg 0
A        1       0       0    1      4
B        0       0       1    1      0
C        1       1       0    1      1
D        0       0       0    5      5
E        0       0       1    0      9
```

I want to check if any of the rows of `df` can satisfy the criteria: `df1[i,1]>0` and `df1[i,2]>0`. `i` goes from `1` to `nrow(df1)`. For example:

when `i = 1`, I want to check if any of the row of `df` can satisfy the condition: `aa > 0 & ac > 0`. Since, none of the rows satisfy the condition, the code will return `0`. when `i = 2`, the condition would be: `ac > 0 & tg > 0`. here one row of `df` (5th row) satisfy the condition, so the code will return `1`. The output will be saved to a new column of `df1`. The output will be as follows:

```
indx1   indx2   count_occ
aa 1    ac       0
ac      tg 0     1
```

I have tried as follows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    d1 = subset(df, as.name(df1[i,1]) > 0 & as.name(df1[i,2]) > 0)
    if(nrow(d1) >= 1){
      df1[i,3] = 1
    }else{
      df1[i,3] = 0
    }
  }
```

But `d1 = subset(df, as.name(df1[i,1]) > 0 & as.name(df1[i,2]) > 0)` is not giving me the correct output. Any help would be highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map`

1. Loop over the 'indx1', 'indx2' columns of 'df' in `Map`
2. Extract the corresponding columns of 'df1' - `df1[[x]]`, `df1[[y]]`
3. Create the multiple logical expression with `>` and `&`
4. Check if there `any` `TRUE` value from the rows of 'df1'
5. Coerce to binary (`+(` - or use `as.integer`)
6. Convert the `list` output to a `vector` - `unlist` and assign it to create the 'count_occ' column in 'df'

```
df$count_occ <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) 
      +(any(df1[[x]] > 0 & df1[[y]] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)), df$indx1, df$indx2))
```

-output

```
df
  indx1 indx2 count_occ
1  aa 1    ac         0
2    ac  tg 0         1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(indx1 = c("aa 1", "ac"), indx2 = c("ac", "tg 0"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), `aa 1` = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `ab 2` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ac = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), `bd 5` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 0L), `tg 0` = c(4L, 0L, 
1L, 5L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. if I need to create a column with how many matched rows of df1 are found for each row of df, how can I modify the code?

Comment: @user3642360 You may change the `any` to `sum` and then exclude those having 0 values for sum

Answer (score 2):

I think the following solution can be used with a `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    if(df1[j, df[i, 1]] > 0 & df1[j, df[i, 2]] > 0) {
      df1[j, "id"] <- 1
    } else {
      df1[j, "id"] <- 0
    }
  }
  if(any(df1$id == 1)) {
    df[i, "count"] <- 1
  } else {
    df[i, "count"] <- 0
  }
}

  indx1 indx2 count
1  aa 1    ac     0
2    ac  tg 0     1
```